# How to copy data of datetime column to another column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I copy data of all column from datetime column to another column without hour minute and second.

Table A

```
      ID    Time                              Time2

       1      2012-08-08 00:38:59.783         NULL
```

After copy

```
      ID     Time                              Time2

      1      2012-08-08 00:38:59.783          2012-08-08
```

Comment: What's that "other column"'s datatype?? Also: calling a column `Time` is a very poor choice - that's a T-SQL reserved keyword and will cause all kinds of grief - try to use more descriptive, less "general-purpose" column names

Comment: It will be date (day month year)

Comment: Write an update statement to set the new column and apply respective date formating function to achieve desired format. Leverage `datepart` function if you are using Sybase ASE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update table
set time2=cast (time as date)
```

## [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/31085)

Comment: I tried this query but Time2= 2012-08-08 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #temp (Time datetime, Time2 date)

insert into #temp values ('2012-08-08 00:38:59.783', null)
insert into #temp values ('2012-08-05 02:30:34.123', null)

update #temp set Time2 = Time

select * from #temp
drop table #temp
```

Comment: @Vijaykumar Hadalgi the question is tagged with SQL server 2008, which automatically casts datetime to date.  My solution does work, you can test it. I am curious to know why you say it doesn't work?

Comment: +1 ..ya ! it's good ..my bad! [jus put the demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/31171)

Comment: i think the Time2 is of datetime ! see comments in above answer ! in that case your answer fails ! [see here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/31171)